# permanently save modified dataset

Tags: sas, directory, dataset, permanent

I know this is a very basic question but my code keeps failing when trying to run what I found through the help documentation.

Up to now I have been running an analysis project off of the .WORK directory which I understand gets wiped out every time a session ends. I have done a bunch of data cleaning and preparation and do not want to have to do that every time before I start my analysis.

So I understand, from reading this: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001310720.htm that I have to output the cleaned dataset to a non-temporary directory.

Steps I have taken so far:
1) created a new Library called "Project"
2) Saved it in a folder that I have under "my folders" in SAS
3) My code for saving the cleaned dataset to the "Project" library is as follows:

```
PROC SORT DATA=FAA_ALL NODUPKEY;
BY GROUND_SPEED;
DATA PROJECT.FAA_ALL;
RUN;
```

Then I run this code in a new program:

```
PROC PRINT DATA=PROJECT.FAA_ALL;
RUN;
```

It says there are no observations and that the dataset is essentially empty.

Can some tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the `PROC SORT`

```
PROC SORT DATA=FAA_ALL NODUPKEY;
BY GROUND_SPEED;
DATA PROJECT.FAA_ALL;
RUN;
```

Should be

```
PROC SORT DATA=FAA_ALL OUT= PROJECT.FAA_ALL NODUPKEY;
BY GROUND_SPEED;
RUN;
```

That `DATA PROJECT.FAA_ALL` was starting a Data Step creating a blank data set.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. So I was reading the wrong help article from SAS website? Didn't mention an "out" argument.

Comment: I think you were on the right track, this was just a syntax bug in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Something else worth mentioning: your data step didn't do what you might have expected because you had no set statement.  Your code was equivalent to:

```
PROC SORT DATA=WORK.FAA_ALL NODUPKEY;
BY GROUND_SPEED;
RUN;

DATA PROJECT.FAA_ALL;
 SET _NULL_;
RUN;
```

`PROJECT.FAA_ALL` is empty because nothing was read in.

The `SORT` procedure implicitly sorts a dataset *in-place*.  You could have SAS move the sorted data by adding the `set` statement to your data step:

```
PROC SORT DATA=WORK.FAA_ALL NODUPKEY;
BY GROUND_SPEED;
RUN;

DATA PROJECT.FAA_ALL;
 SET WORK.FAA_ALL;
RUN;
```

However, this still takes two steps, and requires extra disk I/O.  Using the `out` option in a SAS procedure (as in DomPazz's answer) is almost always faster and more efficient than using a data step just to move data.